# java.util.zip.ZipException during AAR deployment for Axis 2 on jBoss

Tags: web-services, deployment, jboss, apache-axis

```
Error: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 10587 but got 10576 bytes) at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.setClassLoader(DeploymentFileData.java:117) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:66) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0):

I too got this exception when i try to deploy apache-axis rampart,rahas, and addressing modules in a non server environment. What I did was I extracted the zip files kept the extracted folders inside "modules" folder.

[enter link description here](http://sahanlm.tumblr.com/post/103025556372/when-trying-to-deploy-apache-axis-rampart-modules-are)